# Google Apps Script to Hide a Row when both of the checkboxes in Col15 and Col18 are checkmarked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the image, the first checkbox is in Col15 and second checkbox is in Col18. I need that when **both** the boxes are checkmarked, the row should autohide!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSDRp.png)

I am very new at it, so could not really get the hang of how to achieve my objective.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from your question and your sample image. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly, then you can try to hide the row (where both cells in column 15 and 18 are checked) with this script...

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,18).getValue() == true){
    const sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var currentRow = e.range.rowStart;
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const value15 = sheet.getRange(currentRow,15).getValue();
    if (value15){
      sheet.hideRows(currentRow);
    }
} else if (e.range.columnStart == 18 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,15).getValue() == true){
    const sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var currentRow = e.range.rowStart;
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const value18 = sheet.getRange(currentRow,18).getValue();
    if (value18){
      sheet.hideRows(currentRow);
    }
}
}
```

This is a little bit simplified version:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 15 || e.range.columnStart == 18){
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,15).getValue()==true && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,18).getValue()==true){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  } 
}
```

Update for delete all rows with checked fields in column 15 and 18, executed with menu button...

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
            .createMenu("Menu")
            .addItem("Hide Checked", "hideChecked")
            .addToUi();
}

function hideChecked(){
  const activeSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(activeSheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = lastRow; i > 0 ; i--)
  {
    if (sheet.getRange(i,15).getValue()==true && sheet.getRange(i,18).getValue()==true){
      sheet.hideRows(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great help! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Can you also help me achieve this: create a custom menu for hiding all items where col15 and coll18 are checked? Or, a button that hides all rows where col15 and col18 are checked?

Comment: @Fristo7cups I updated the solution. Just copy 2 functions and reload the document. Then, click on Menu >> Hide Checked

Comment: @Fristo7cups Also, dont forget to comment or remove existing onEdit function, to prevent hiding rows after checking both cells in a row...

Comment: Thanks again! But the script did not work using the menu button. It said 'Running Script' but did not hide the rows.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask: Is there a way that other users could hide the rows even though the large part of the sheet is protected (had to protect the cells because accidental edits on those cells wiped out the importrange data.)

Comment: Do you consider my initial answer as a solution for your initial question?

Comment: Yes, the initial answer did solve the initial question! I am using that on the dash, that was a great help.

Comment: Ok, since you are a new user, I will try to explain. You can check this answer as a solution.